# What determines the viewport size for a QGraphicsView?

Tags: qt

I have a custom class that inherits from `QGraphicsView`, and I've overridden `void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)`, but I'm confused at the value that gets passed in the `size` field of the `event`, as it doesn't seem to correlate to any size that I'm setting anywhere in my app.

The size I'm getting is `4798x1078` (If I dig a little in the callstack, I can see that it's originally `4800x1080`), but I can't understand why. My monitor is running at `3840x2160`, so there doesn't seem to be any relationship there either (I do have two monitors, so I'll try turning one off, and see if that changes anything).

I guess my question is basically, what determines the viewport size, and how can I control it so it matches the size of my `QGraphicsView`.

Edit: Ok, turning off the second monitor changes the viewport size to `1918x1078`, which I guess is interesting. And also changing the Windows display scaling from 1.5 to 1.0 also changes the values..

Answer (score 0):

I think I've solved my problems for now by explicitly calling `QGraphicsView::setGeometry` from the resize handler of the widget that contained the view, using that widget's geometry, which makes the view's viewport the same size as the widget, which is what I wanted.